# property not find on object "the name of the class i've created" , and the viewcontroller is not recognizing the method which defined inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I using Xcode 4.6 for calculator application and I am getting three errors, can you shed a light what might causing them?

Here are the 3 errors

> property 'pushElement' not find on object type "CalculatorBrain",
>
> property 'enter pressed' not found on object type CalculatorviewController
>
> property 'perform operation' not find on object type "CalculatorBrain"

This is part of the code that i am getting error in it which `CalculatorviewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)enterPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    [_Brain.pushElement :self.display.text];       ......first error ....
    userIntheMiddleOfEnteringText= NO; 
}

- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (userIntheMiddleOfEnteringText)
        self.enterPressed;                     ........second error.....

    else {
        double result = [_Brain.performOperation];        ... third error...
        self.display.text=[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%g",result];
    }

}
```

and the `CalculatorBrain.m` code is

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@implementation CalculatorBrain

-(void)pushElement:(double)operand {
    NSNumber *operandObject=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];
                            
    [self.stack addObject:operandObject];
}

-(double) popElement {
    NSNumber *popedNumber=[self.stack lastObject];
    if (popedNumber)
    {
        [_stack removeLastObject];
    }
  
    return [popedNumber doubleValue];
}

-(double)performOperation:(NSString*)operation {
    double  result = 0;
    if( [operation isEqualToString: @"+"]){
        result  =self. popElement + self.popElement;
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:  @"*"]){
        result=self.popElement*self.popElement;
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"-" ]) {
        double operand=self.popElement;
        result=self.popElement - operand ;
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
        double divisor =self.popElement;
        result= self.popElement/ divisor;
    }
  
    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: As @rmaddy says, you may want to review Objective-C syntax (and in particular, dot notation) before proceeding. I started learning Objective-C after the dot notation was already popular, but I didn't use it for a couple of months, because I wanted to be sure I could wrap my head around the message-sending paradigm. The same exercise may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three errors are simple errors that indicate that you don't yet understand the basics of Objective-C. You need to learn the language first. Learn how to call methods and pass parameters.

The first error:

```
[_Brain.pushElement :self.display.text];
```

This should be:

```
[_Brain pushElement:self.display.text];
```

Here you want to call the `pushElement:` method on the `_Brain` object.

The second error:

```
self.enterPressed;
```

That indicates that you are trying to accessing a property named `enterPressed` on `self`. But there is no such property. There is a method named `enterPressed:` and this takes a `UIButton` as an argument. So you need to call it like this:

```
[self enterPress:sender];
```

The third error:

```
double result = [_Brain.performOperation];
```

Here you want to call the `performOperation` method but there isn't one. There is a method named `performOperation:`. This takes a parameter of type `NSString`. It must be called like this:

```
double result = [_Brain performOperation:@"some operation"];
```

The missing piece here is the operation you wish to pass. There is no obvious indication of where that comes from. Perhaps the button title.